# php права на загруженный файл

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

Через crontab запускаю скрипт, который конвертирует ранее загруженный через форму видео файл. Если запускать скрипт через браузер, то всё работает нормально, но через cron - не хочет. Подозреваю, что дело в правах на загруженный файл, но как правильно их настроить - не знаю. ОС - Ubuntu 16.04, сервер - apache.

Comment: Есть возможность посмотреть права, владельца и группу для обоих вариантов файлов? Например через ls -la?

Comment: У загруженного файла: -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас права на файл 0644, т.е. владелец может читать и редактировать файл - больше никто ничего с ним сделать не может. Владельцем является пользователь www-data. Как вариант, можно добавить пользователя из под которого запускается скрипт по cron в группу www-data и выставлять права на файлы 0664, например, PHP-функцией chmod(). Если это не возможно придется выставлять права 0666, позволяя редактировать файл из под любого пользователя.

Comment: Пользователя в группу добавил, права выставил, но не заработало. Может ли быть проблема в том, что сейчас вот так -rw-r--r--, а должно быть вот так: -rw-rw-r--?

Comment: Да, у старых файлов права тоже нужно поправить.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у видео файла при загрзке автоматически выставляются такие права и поменять я им могу уже только после загрузки. А как выставить, чтобы файл сразу загружался с нужными правами?

Comment: По умолчанию файл загружается в папку /tmp, откуда вы его копируете в папку назначения или функций move_uploaded_file() или copy() - нельзя вклиниться на этом этапе?

Comment: Проблема обнаружена: путь к файлу передаётся в скрипт через сессию и именно через сессию выполняться не хочет. Если явно указать имя нужного файла, то всё работает. Есть ли какая-то возможность взаимодействия cron с сессией?

Comment: @jSoN88 Вообще добраться до сессий можно, но чтобы сделать это по-человечески придется переопределить механизм сессии с сохранением данных в удобной для вас форме (база данных, NoSQL-решние вроде memcached или redis). Можно конечно шерстить папку с файлами сессий, но это не очень удобно. Если вы сложите сессии в таблицу реляционной или NoSQL базы данных - вам поискать среди них будет сильно проще, но это лучше обсудить уже в рамках другого вопроса.